# How do I use (compile) zlib (gzip functions) compression library within Intel Pin tool?

Tags: makefile, compilation, zlib, dlopen, intel-pin

I have libz-dev installed on ubuntu 20.04. I added the following lines in pin/source/tools/SimpleExamples/icount.cpp :

```
#include <zlib.h>
```

and in main():

```
gzFile gp;
gp = gzopen("compressed_log_file", "ab");
gzbuffer(gp, 100000);
```

My makefile build rule for linking is:

```
$(OBJDIR)icount$(PINTOOL_SUFFIX): $(OBJDIR)icount$(OBJ_SUFFIX)
    $(LINKER) $(TOOL_LDFLAGS_NOOPT) $(LINK_EXE)$@ $< $(TOOL_LPATHS) $(TOOL_LIBS) -lz
```

which follows the [Intel Pin User Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/index.html#BuildingOutOfKit) except for the -lz flag I added.

I can make with no errors, but when I run the pin tool, I get this error:

```
E: Unable to load /pin/source/tools/SimpleExamples/obj-intel64/icount.so: dlopen failed: library "libz.so.1" not found
```

My execution command is:

```
../../../../pin -t icount.so -- ls
```

1. Am I linking correctly?
2. Should I be trying to link statically instead of using dlopen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to compile directly, so I ended up just using the pin tool and then redirecting the output (from stderr) and piping it into the gzip command line utility.

```
./path_to_pin/pin -t icount.so -- ls 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | gzip -c > my_compression_output.txt
```